# application.properties datasource problem

Tags: maven, spring-boot

In my ongoing quest to make saving to two datasources working I'm trying to add two datasources to my application.properties file by giving them custom prefixes like it's done by the official spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources.
When I do this and I insert data it won't save to the mysql database, I end up with empty datasets and an error (see below). However, if I use the original prefix on a datasource and a changed prefix on the other database it does save, but only in the database with the unchanged prefix.

This is my configuration for user (db1):

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;

public class UserConfiguration {


    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.db1")
    public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.db1.configuration")
    public HikariDataSource firstDataSource() {
        return firstDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();

    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(firstDataSource())
                .packages("User.class")//User.class
                .persistenceUnit("users")
                .build();
    }
}
```

configuration for product (db2)

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;


public class ProductConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.db2")
    public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.db2.configuration")
    public BasicDataSource secondDataSource() {
        return secondDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean productEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(secondDataSource())
                .packages("Product.class")//Product.class
                .persistenceUnit("products")
                .build();
    }
}
```

application.properties file that doesn't work

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.datasource.db1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db1?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.db1.username=user
spring.datasource.db1.password=pass
spring.datasource.db1.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.db1.configuration.maximum-pool-size=30

spring.datasource.db2.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db2?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.db2.username=user
spring.datasource.db2.password=pass
spring.datasource.db2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.db2.max-total=30
```

error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

application.properties file that works half. Only data to db 1 is saved.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db1?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.configuration.maximum-pool-size=30

spring.datasource.db2.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db2?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.db2.username=user
spring.datasource.db2.password=pass
spring.datasource.db2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.db2.max-total=30
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.multidb</groupId>
    <artifactId>multipledb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.47</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

So this leaves me to believe that my application doesn't accept a changed prefix. What am I missing here?
I've tried to use different maven dependency versions, different driver notations, tried adding an H2 database dependency. But I'm stumbling from error to error.

Comment: post please your pom.xml or build.gradle file.

Comment: Added! Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Could it be that you forget to set @Configuration on your Classes ProductConfiguration and UserConfiguration?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try this out tomorrow. In the meanwhile, could you please elaborate? The example on multiple datasources in the spring documentation doesn't mention this. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, I tried your suggestion. Now I have a new error about my product class not being a managed type. After (again) going through dozens of stackoverflow posts I double checked all my settings. Tried all the suggestions but to no avail. I officially quit with this project now. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: You have created your class as configuration, where is your configuration annotation @Configuration?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. @Grauzone suggested this also (see above). I've  changed it but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Ok try to do this:

you have to split your repositories like this:

```
src/main/java
- com.foobar   
  - user
    - domain
    - repo
  - products
    - domain
    - repo
```

In repo put your @Repository interfaces and in domain your entities.

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db1?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.configuration.maximum-pool-size=30

db2.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db2?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
db2.datasource.username=user
db2.datasource.password=pass
db2.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db2.datasource.max-total=30
```

Configuration for your DB1 (first datasource)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
  basePackages = { "com.foobar.user.repo" }
)
public class UserConfiguration {

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder
      .dataSource(dataSource)
      .packages("com.foobar.user.domain")
      .persistenceUnit("userPU")
      .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

Configuration for your DB2 (Secondy datasource)

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory",
  transactionManagerRef = "db2TransactionManager",
  basePackages = { "com.foobar.products.repo" }
)
public class ProductConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "db2DataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "db2.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "db2EntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
  db2EntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return
      builder
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("com.foobar.products.domain")
        .persistenceUnit("productPU")
        .build();
  }
  @Bean(name = "db2TransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager(@Qualifier("db2EntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory db2EntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(db2EntityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It worked here.